# How do I read the wall of a facebook event?

Tags: php, facebook, events, sdk

I have a successfully authenticated user logged into my app through facebook, I want to read the wall / information of an event the user created. My code is returning an empty array with just [data] => (). The event id is valid taken from the URL of the event. Any links as to where to find relevant documentation on this is greatly appreciated. Do I need to request any extra permissions from the user when logging in?

```
    <?php
    require 'facebook.php';

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => 'XXXXXXXX',
      'secret' => 'XXXXXXXX',
      'cookie' => true
    ));

    $user = $facebook->getUser();

    $page_id = 'XXXXXXXX';
    $pageFeed = $facebook->api('/'.$page_id.'/feed');

    print_r($pageFeed);

    ?>
```

Comment: First of all is the event public or restricted to a limited group?

Comment: The event is now public and the code works, even if it's restricted to the user's friends can I not view grab its data if the user that logs into my app created the event?

Comment: If the user that logs into your app and you have asked for the user_events permission then you can retrieve the data that you want. Though totally unlinked but just a suggestion, could you try the same with [Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) and check out the results?

Comment: I had it working, and now it's decided not to work and I haven't made any changes to the code. So i made a new event and used graph explorer, this returns the metadata for the event but i get a blank data array when i request the feed data from either event...

Comment: Does the graph explorer also returns nothing? Does your event has any post except its creation ?

Comment: The graph explorer returns the event information, there are posts on the wall of the event but i can't return these when requesting the feed. I was able to fetch these just the other day though without issue. I made a new event and the same problem occurs.

Comment: If its possible, could you provide your event id ?

Comment: http://www.facebook.com/events/427800533942708/

Comment: I also just tried to submit a graph query in both the explorer and my code with an access token and this also returned an empty data array.

Comment: I can also retrieve a list of who is attending the event

Comment: After you login to Facebook check [this](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=427800533942708%2Ffeed), I am able to retrieve the feed from the event

Comment: I'm logged into facebook and that link returns a blank data array.

Comment: Okay, i literally ran it about 10 minutes ago and it didn't work. I've played some chess, came back and refreshed it and it worked. Is there something i'm missing or does facebook's API have a rand function deciding whether or not to send a response...?

Comment: Could you change the $facebook->api('/'.$page.'/feed'); to $facebook->api('/'.$pageID.'/feed','GET'); and tell if the problem persists

Comment: Done that, no change to apps behaviour though. I've identified that when i run the script whilst logged into facebook it returns an empty array however when i logout of facebook and then run the script it works.

Comment: This is rather very very strange thing, it should be consistent, and there is no error I could detect on your code.Could you try printing out the Access tokens($facebook->getAccessToke()) when you login and after you logout and use them on Graph Explorer to check whether the problem lies within the Aceess Tokens

Comment: I used the access token i get when i login on graph explorer and still can't retrieve the feed, i don't have an access token when i logout.

Answer (score 0):

Check you have the `user_events` [Permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) - this is needed to access a user's events and/or the feed of those events

Comment: Thanks, I've added this permission in my permissions dialog under user and friend permissions but i'm still getting the same result. My app isn't even asking for these permissions when I authenticate. I've done some further research and can't understand what else I need to do, any ideas?

Comment: look at the [Authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) documentation - you need the user to authorise your app - the app settings on developers.facebook.com apply only when Facebook renders the authentication dialog, which is a relatively small percentage of the time - most of the time you need to direct users to the auth dialog after you detect they've granted you no/insufficient permissions